# Arch Linux guest (VirtualBox): cannot configure X

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, virtualbox, openbox

I'm trying to install and configure Xorg on my Arch Linux virtual machine. I can start the X server with `startx` but when I try to generate the configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the command `Xorg :0 -configure` it fails. Here the steps I made up to now:

1. Installed The Guest Additions via `pacman` with the packages `virtualbox-guest-utils`and `virtualbox-guest-modules-arch` (I'm using the standard linux kernel, I also installed the headers `linux-headers`) as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_Guest_Additions);
2. Created the `/etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf` file with the three lines

   ```
   vboxguest
   vboxsf
   vboxvideo
   ```

   and enabled `vboxservice.service`;
3. Installed the packages `mesa` and `xf86-video-vesa`;
4. Installed `xorg-server`, `xorg-server-utils`and `xorg-apps`;
5. Installed `openbox`and `xterm` and set `~/.xintrc` as follows:

   ```
   xterm &
   exec openbox
   ```
6. Rebooted.

the `startx`command works, but when I try to generate the `xorg.conf`file it fails. Here the `Xorg.0.log`file:

```
[  1460.360] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[  1460.362] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1460.365] Build Operating System: Linux 4.5.4-1-ARCH x86_64 
[  1460.367] Current Operating System: Linux ArchLinux 4.7.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 20 23:02:56 CEST 2016 x86_64
[  1460.368] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/VolGroupArch-root rw quiet
[  1460.369] Build Date: 19 July 2016  05:54:24PM
[  1460.370]  
[  1460.371] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  1460.373]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1460.373] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1460.378] (==) Log file: "/home/luigi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Sep  2 20:00:40 2016
[  1460.378] (II) Loader magic: 0x821d40
[  1460.378] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1460.378]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1460.378]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[  1460.378]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[  1460.378]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[  1460.383] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c1
[  1460.384] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1460.385] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 8 paused 0
[  1460.388] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 80ee:beef:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/67108864, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1460.389] List of video drivers:
[  1460.389]    vesa
[  1460.389]    modesetting
[  1460.389] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1460.389] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1460.389] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1460.389]    compiled for 1.18.0, module version = 2.3.4
[  1460.389]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1460.389]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[  1460.389] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1460.389] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1460.389] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1460.389]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[  1460.389]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1460.389]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[  1460.389] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  1460.389] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1460.389] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[  1460.389] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1460.389] (++) Using config file: "/home/luigi/xorg.conf.new"
[  1460.389] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1460.390] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[  1460.390] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  1460.390] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[  1460.390] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[  1460.390] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  1460.390] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  1460.390] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1460.390] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1460.390] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1460.390] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1460.390] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[  1460.390] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/").
[  1460.390] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[  1460.390] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[  1460.390]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1460.390]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/").
[  1460.390] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/
[  1460.390] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1460.390] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  1460.390] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  1460.390] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  1460.390] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  1460.390] Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
Configuration failed.
```

I'm a beginner with Arch, I know I'm missing something stupid.
Thanks in advice for you help.

Comment: In general you do not need to configure xorg.conf and if `startx` is working, there is probably even less reason to mess around. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg) says *If you are already running an X server, use a different display, for example Xorg :2 -configure.* It is not clear from your description if you have stop the xserver after running `startx`.

Comment: Yes, I checked that no other sessions were open. However, as you suggested, I will try to write my xorg.conf by myself and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: You've made it too complicated. All you need is to install `virtualbox-guest-utils` and it should then work out of the box after a reboot. Remove your `xorg.conf`, it's not needed, and since it's now modular, if you need to change the keyboard layout, `localectl` can do it for you.

Comment: Good point, that's a better solution. The problem with the Guest Additions is that the service `vboxservice.service` seems to be broken to me. For example, the display adjustment utility is not launched at login, but if I type `VBoxClient --display` everything works! What could it be?